# Ffmpeg zoom the video but there is no sound

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, zoom

```
ffmpeg -y -i 33.mp4 -vf "scale=iw:ih,zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,3),3),zoom+1.8000,zoom-0.0865)':d=1:x='320-(320/zoom)':y='240-(240/zoom)'" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -an zoom.mp4
```

Everything is Ok but there is no sound of the video.

What codes can I add to hear the sound?

Comment: double check 33.mp4 is encoded with aac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `-an`. It means "no audio".